# Arduino RS485 shield to RS485 temperature & humidity sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, rs485

I’m try to get data from rs485 is not work please advise to me.

```
1.  Try to connect PC usb485 to DY-MD02 is work.
    Send command “AUTO” or “READ”

2.  Try to Arduino rs485 shield to DY-MD02 is not work.
    Send command “AUTO”
```

my code

''''

```
char command[4] = {'A', 'U', 'T', 'O'};

int n = sizeof(command)/sizeof(command[0]);   // Number of elements in an array

String incoming = "";   // for incoming serial string data

void setup()

{

      // initialize serial ports
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(EN,OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(EN,HIGH); //Enable high, RS485 shield waiting to transmit data
      Serial.write(command,n); //Test send command Auto,Read to RS485
      delay(500);
}

void loop()

{

      String temp;
      digitalWrite(EN,LOW); //Enable low, RS485 shield waiting to receive data

      while(Serial.available() > 0 )
      {
          temp=Serial.read();
          Serial.println(temp);
          delay(1000); //Delay for some time, waiting for data transmitted
      }

}
```

''''

---

if change code to = ***Serial.readString()*** not show anything.

please help me
Thank

[image: XY-MD02]

[image: PC USB485 is OK]

[image: Data]

---

to Juraj

Maker tell me can connect with Arduino uno and send manual to me.

see in attach file.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: exact model or datasheet of shield please? does it communicate with Uno over hardware Serial?

Comment: model of the shield?

Comment: it looks like your serial input doesn't provide `end of line` characters **(\r\n)** at the end. `readString` function fetch the character value step by step and store them in buffer till `EOL` character are received. After receiving `EOL` character it returns the string.

Comment: @Vaibhav, readString doesn't care about line ends. it returns after timeout

Comment: I want details about the RS485 shield

Comment: To Juraj = https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobotMediaWikiMarkDown/wiki/Arduino_RS485_Shield_SKU__DFR0259

Comment: your shield on the photo is different

Answer (score 1):

i'm tray change this code to readStringUntil, is OK

```
if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    temp = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(temp);
    delay(1000); //Delay for some time, waiting for data transmitted
  }
```

Thank all for help me
^^

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest try to use [Modbus Master](https://github.com/4-20ma/ModbusMaster) library it will help you get the data from sensor. The issue with the code is you are only sending the command but while interfacing with modbus there is a packet/ frame which you need to form and then send it the packet/frame format is in the below diagram[image: Modbus Packet]

I will prefer use an Arduino Mega or other arduino which have more than 1 Serial port for communication. I also faced a similar issue but it was resolved after digging a little bit you can have a look at the issue [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78648/read-internal-registers-of-rs485?)